# First row hidden by the navbar in a Twitter Bootstrap-Website

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I have a problem with the navigation on the following website:

http://www.Ghitulescu.de/beta/index2.html

While clicking on a navbar-item (was / wieviel / wann / wo / wer) the site *jumps* to the specific section but the first row of it (that's the h2-title!) is covered by the navbar itself.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Regards,
Vlad

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using the fixed navbar you need to..

1) Remove the `margin-top:50px` from the top `jumbotron`

2) Add padding to the top of the body (ie: `body { padding-top: 70px; }`)

This is guidance from the Bootstrap docs (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top)..

```
**Body padding required**
The fixed navbar will overlay your other content, unless you add padding to the top of the <body>. Try out your own values or use our snippet below. Tip: By default, the navbar is 50px high.
```